# How to print short caption on each page before header of long flextable (rmarkdown, word output)

Tags: r, ms-word, r-markdown, flextable

I have a long flextable, and I knit it to word output. My flextable has a caption, and I want to print a 'additional caption' (short version of my caption) on each page before the header of my flextable. I am trying to find the solution, but I can't find any information about it.
Is there any solution for it?

````
---

output: 
  word_document
  
---

```{r}
library(flextable)
ft1 <- flextable(iris)

library(officer)
ft1 <- set_caption(ft1, caption = "My caption",  autonum = run_autonum() )
autofit(ft1)

```
````

The 'additional caption' that I need is marked red on the image attached below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Something like that?

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: word_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```


```{r}
library(flextable)
ft1 <- flextable(iris)

library(officer)
ft1 <- add_header_lines(ft1, "a short caption")
ft1 <- align(ft1, i = 1, part = "header", align = "right")
ft1 <- color(ft1, i = 1, part = "header", color = "orange")
ft1 <- set_caption(ft1, caption = "My caption",  autonum = run_autonum() )
autofit(ft1)

```
````

[image]

Comment: Thanks, David! 
It's a nice solution, but I don't want to print "a short caption" on the first page. Do you have any idea to fix it?

Comment: Sorry. I am not aware of such functionality in Word

Comment: Hi, David!
[Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/404409/how-to-add-the-caption-for-a-part-of-long-table-which-transferred-to-a-new-page?newreg=069f328d6a1343e78673b29c6f9e2e3d) is a [tag:TEX] solution for my problem.  Is it possible, to do something like it with [tag:flextable]?

Comment: my point is this only exist for PDF, not in Word nor HTML

Comment: Ok, I understand. Thanks!